# How to cache a list in spring?

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-el

I am using spring. I want to cache following method:

```
@Cacheable(cacheName = "xxx", key = "'foo_'.concat(#va1)")
public void foo(String var1, List<String> var2) { ... }
```

I want to include the value set of var2 into cache key. I know
  `key = "'foo_'.concat(#va1).concat('_').concat(#var2)"` is wrong. (Because `(#var2)` will return its memory address, not values).

What should I do?

Comment: have you tried `#{var2.toString()}`

Comment: what are you trying to cache? as there is no return? usually a method can be cached so the return will be retrieved from cache.

Comment: sorry. it should have a return. I make a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the hashCode of the List:

```
key = "'foo_'.concat(#va1).concat('_').concat(#var2.hashCode())"
```

OR

```
key = "'foo_'.concat(#va1).concat('_').concat(#var2.toString())"
```

give it a try.

With the second one you are risking that your key might get to  long according to the size of the list.